# Using IdentityDbContext with BreezeJS AspNetCore

Tags: asp.net-core, breeze, identityserver4

I cannot figure out how to get Breeze to return MetaData when I use  IdentityDbContext

My Context is as follows

```
    public partial class MyContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string>
        {
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {


    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany(u => u.Claims).WithOne().HasForeignKey(c => c.UserId).IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany(u => u.Roles).WithOne().HasForeignKey(r => r.UserId).IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().HasMany(r => r.Claims).WithOne().HasForeignKey(c => c.RoleId).IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().HasMany(r => r.Users).WithOne().HasForeignKey(r => r.RoleId).IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        }

        }
```

In my ConfigureServices:

```
// add identity
   services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

My Default Controller is:

```
 [Route("breeze/[action]")]
[BreezeQueryFilter]
public class DefaultController : Controller
{
    private readonly NyContext _context;
    private readonly UnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly MyPersistenceManager _persistenceManager;

    // called via DI 
    public DefaultController(MyContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(context);
        _persistenceManager = new MyPersistenceManager(context);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Metadata()
    {
        return Ok(_persistenceManager.Metadata());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public SaveResult SaveChanges([FromBody] JObject saveBundle)
    {
        return _unitOfWork.Commit(saveBundle);
    }
}
```

When I execute and test like so :

http://localhost:3333/Breeze/MetaData

I get the following error:

> {"$id":"1","$type":"Breeze.AspNetCore.ErrorDto, Breeze.AspNetCore.NetCore","Code":0,"Message":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","StackTrace":"   at Breeze.Persistence.EFCore.MetadataBuilder.BuildAssocName(INavigation prop) in C:\git\Breeze\breeze.server.net\AspNetCore\Breeze.Persistence.EFCore\MetadataBuilder.cs:line 138\r\n   at Breeze.Persistence.EFCore.MetadataBuilder.CreateNavProperty(INavigation p) in C:\git\Breeze\breeze.server.net\AspNetCore\Breeze.Persistence.EFCore\MetadataBuilder.cs:line 128\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.ToList()\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at Breeze.Persistence.EFCore.MetadataBuilder.CreateMetaType(IEntityType et, Dictionary`2 dbSetMap) in C:\\git\\Breeze\\breeze.server.net\\AspNetCore\\Breeze.Persistence.EFCore\\MetadataBuilder.cs:line 89\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.ToList()\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at Breeze.Persistence.EFCore.MetadataBuilder.GetMetadataFromContext(DbContext dbContext) in C:\\git\\Breeze\\breeze.server.net\\AspNetCore\\Breeze.Persistence.EFCore\\MetadataBuilder.cs:line 21\r\n   at Breeze.Persistence.EFCore.EFPersistenceManager`1.BuildJsonMetadata() in C:\git\Breeze\breeze.server.net\AspNetCore\Breeze.Persistence.EFCore\EFPersistenceManager.cs:line 109\r\n   at Breeze.Persistence.PersistenceManager.Metadata() in C:\git\Breeze\breeze.server.net\AspNetCore\Breeze.Persistence\PersistenceManager.cs:line 34\r\n   at DictionaryPortalServer.Controllers.DefaultController.Metadata() in C:\Users\MrTou\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Dictionary Project\DP Server\DictionaryPortalServer\Controllers\DefaultController.cs:line 32\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__12.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__10.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__14.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__23.MoveNext()","EntityErrors":null}

I know my context is working because if I use another controller to get data like so:

http://localhost:3333/breeze/Summary/CartOrders

I get data back. It's only when I try to get MetaData that I get the error.

It seems like Breeze cannot generate the MetaData becuase of

ApplicationUser and ApplicationRole

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!!

Comment: Does it work if you comment out your `OnModelCreating` method?